# db query SQL command

Tags: sql

I'm getting confused on what is actually happening here. Can anyone clarify? I'm pretty new to SQL. I know there are 4 tables (users, departments, locations, units).

```
function get_info($user)
{
    return $this->db->query('SELECT u.*,
                            d.id AS deptID,
                            l.id AS locid,
                            t.UnitName AS unitname FROM users AS u
                            JOIN departments AS d ON d.id == u.Department
                            JOIN locations AS l ON l.id == u.Location
                            JOIN units AS t ON t.id == d.Unit
                            WHERE u.ID == '.$this->db->escape($user))->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context (e.g., which SQL database is this targeting, where you found the code)?

Comment: pretty straight forward...it's taking all the fields from the user table and going to departments to get deptID, locations to get locID and units to get the unitname. Filtering by userID.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What is it that you are confused about, exactly? The answer to your question as it stands would be a very basic explanation of what the code does, and probably wouldn't tell you anything that you don't already know.

Comment: pardon my ignorance. Confused on how the multiple JOINs with the 4 tables was working. I think it makes sense now.

Comment: Actually...the departments and locations join look useless.  It's grabbing l.id to display, but l.id is the key used...so the join could be dropped and u.location could be used instead of l.id.  Only the join to units is translating something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sometimes helps me understand SQL queries to group them by their parts: what, where, how;

Select what?

`SELECT 
u.*,
d.id AS deptID,
l.id AS locid,
t.UnitName AS unitname`

Select from where?:

`FROM users AS u`

How should it be selected?

`JOIN departments AS d ON d.id == u.Department
JOIN locations AS l ON l.id == u.Location
JOIN units AS t ON t.id == d.Unit`

Any further provisions for how to select it:

`WHERE u.ID == 1`

Aliases for tables also get confusing, I wrote this in reference to what your query is really saying:

1. Select all(`*`) the columns from table alias `u`, true name `users`
2. Select the `id` from table alias `d`, true name `departments`, and call it `deptID`
3. Select the id from table alias `l`, true name  `locations`, and call it `locid`
4. Select the `UnitName` from table alias `t`, true name `units`, and call it `unitname`

Answer (score 0):

Given a user ID in `$user`, this returns the ID of the department that the user is in (from `d.id = u.Department`), the unit name associated with that department (from `t.id = d.Unit`), the ID of the location of the user (from `l.id = u.Location`), and all the information in the `users` table for that user (from `u.*`).